# Python cv2 different output each run when using while(1) (same files)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to use trackbars to set the sensitivity (H,S,V) and trying to calculate the distance between contours.
To find the basic contours I have used, and it works: `numOfObj = len(contours)`.
But for the calculation of the distance of the contour I'm using `math.dist` trying to figure out the distance between the two furthest points in the rectangle. 
and each run returns different output (same set of photos)

```
Between 75 micron 7
Between 105 micron 4
Between 120 micron 3

Between 75 micron 98
Between 105 micron 74
Between 120 micron 4

Between 75 micron 36
Between 105 micron 23
Between 120 micron 8
```

I'm pasting the code below that you can get the idea of how its running

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
import math


# imports the path that you want to read:
path = glob.glob('photos/*.jpg')



#global variable
filterPhoto = 0
remClutter= 0

stopOnPhoto = 0
basicCounter = 0
counterBetween75 = 0
counterBetween105 = 0
counterBetween120 = 0

#trackbar callback fucntion to update HSV value
def callback(x):
    global filterPhoto, remClutter
    #assign trackbar position value to H,S,V High and low variable
    filterPhoto = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Filter','Clutter controller')
    remClutter = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Clutter','Clutter controller')


#create a seperate window named 'Clutter controller' for trackbar
cv2.namedWindow('Clutter controller',2)
cv2.resizeWindow("Clutter controller", 670,10);

#create trackbars
cv2.createTrackbar('Filter','Clutter controller',16,50,callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('Clutter','Clutter controller',175,255,callback)

# print(path)
if len(path) > 0:
    for file in path:
        while(1):
            #read source image
            img = cv2.imread(file)
            #convert sourece image to HSC color mode
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


            hsremClutter = np.array([filterPhoto, 0, remClutter], np.uint8)
            hsv_high = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)



            ######################################################
            #making mask for hsv range
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsremClutter, hsv_high)
            #masking HSV value selected color becomes black
            res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)


            contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,0), 1)
            for c in contours:
                rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                x,y,w,h = rect
                distancePoints = math.dist([w + x, h + y] , [x, y])
                distancePoints = round(distancePoints, 3)
    
                if distancePoints > 75 and distancePoints < 90:
                    counterBetween75 += 1
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y-4),(x+w,y+h), (255,155,0),1)
                    cv2.putText(img, str(distancePoints), (x, y-9), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    print("The file has exceded 75 microns: ", file)

                if distancePoints > 90 and distancePoints < 110:
                    counterBetween105 += 1
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y-4),(x+w,y+h), (255,155,0),1)
                    cv2.putText(img, str(distancePoints), (x, y-9), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    print("The file has exceded 105 microns: ", file)

     
                if distancePoints > 110:
                    counterBetween120 += 1
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y-4),(x+w,y+h), (255,155,0),1)
                    cv2.putText(img, str(distancePoints), (x, y-9), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 255, 0), 1)
                    print("The file has exceded 120 microns: ", file)

                if distancePoints > 0 and distancePoints < 75:
                    basicCounter += 1
                    # cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y-4),(x+w,y+h), (255,155,0),1)
                    # cv2.putText(img, str(distancePoints), (x, y-9), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 255, 0), 1)

            #show image
            # cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
            cv2.imshow('original',img)
            # cv2.imshow('res',res)
        

        
            #waitfor the user to press escape and break the while loop 
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if k == 27:
                break
                
#destroys all window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
numOfObj= len(contours)
print("Below 75 micron", numOfObj)
print("Between 75 micron",counterBetween75)
print("Between 105 micron", counterBetween105)
print("Between 120 micron",counterBetween120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the fix was

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF:
   break
```

Comment: remove the `& 0xFF`. it is redundant and has been since 2017. and it's needlessly complicated. for the `0` argument, this is equivalent to `cv2.WaitKey(0); break` -- and how is this supposed to have fixed "different output each run"?